# Difference of two $scope array in angular js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, scope

Is there a way to return the difference between two array present in a scope in angularjs

For example,

```
 $scope.user1 = ['a', 'b'];
 $scope.user2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Difference of these two should give me an another as
 $scope.user3= ['c','d']

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with angular, you are asking about the basic array concepts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Underscore.js has the difference method for this.

http://underscorejs.org/#difference

```
$scope.user1 = ['a', 'b'];
$scope.user2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$scope.user3 = _.difference($scope.user2, $scope.user1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular can't do anything about it.
Underscore.js is good but I prefer [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/)

[Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) is a utility library delivering consistency, customization, performance, & extras.
And Lo-Dash can

```
$scope.user1 = ['a', 'b'];
$scope.user2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$scope.user3 = _.difference($scope.user2, $scope.user1); // ['c','d']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing there in angularjs. You can look at [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library `difference` method, or may create your own method to calculate the difference.