# Angular - return difference in objects not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How to return the difference of two objects?

```
$scope.a = [
   {name: "Lunchmeat"},
   {name: "Apple"},
   {name: "Bread"},
   {name: "Milk"},
   {name: "Mustard"},
   {name: "Cheese"}
];
$scope.b = [
   {name: "Bread"},
   {name: "Milk"},
   {name: "Mustard"},
   {name: "Cheese"}
]; 

$.grep($scope.a, function (el) {
        if ($.inArray($scope.b,el) == -1) console.log(el);//not working
  });
```

The output I'm looking for is `Object [{name: "Lunchmeat"},{name: "Apple"}]` as this is the difference.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: convert both to sting and then do it.. it would be much easier or else loop thru one array and check if it exist in another.. simple for loop would do

Comment: Possible duplicate [Difference of two $scope array in angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209408/difference-of-two-scope-array-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library and it's function difference:

> "difference_.difference(array, *others)  Similar to without, but
>   returns the values from array that are not present in the other
>   arrays.
>
> _.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
>   => [1, 3, 4]"

In your case it would be:

```
$scope.someVar =_.difference($scope.a,$scope.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing objects using `===` (via `$.inArray`), which will always be `false` for different objects, even if they're *equivalent* objects.

You'll need to loop through the array looking for whether you find an object with the same `name` property instead of the `$.inArray` call. The ES5+ function [`Array#some`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) is useful for this, as is the ES6+ function [`Array#find`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.find). (Both can be shimmed.)